# How to restore nuget packages for Autofixture.NSubstitute for .net6 projects type?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore, nsubstitute, autofixture

Not able to restore packages for `AutoFixture.AutoNSubstitute` in package. This was working fine earlier but now I am not able to build the solution. Projects are using .NET 6. Unit tests inside solution which are using this project are giving error like

> Error CS0234
> The type or namespace name 'AutoNSubstitute' does not exist in the namespace 'AutoFixture' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
> C:\FILEMAN\test\AStorage.Core.Tests\AutoSubstituteDataAttribute.cs    8   Active

I am not able to add the nuget package when I tried adding the nuget package through the Manage Nuget packages .

Please let me know how I can fix this.

Comment: The error you mention looks like compiler error, not a package restore error.

Comment: How can I fix this ?

Comment: There isn't enough information to suggest a fix. Look at the build output (not the error list window) for clues, also check package manager output. And start with the first error you see there. Consider providing a [minimal, reproducing example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the issue.